# Активация кнопки при вводе в input

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, button, авторизация

Необходимо создать форму с логином и паролем в `react`-е, при вводе значений `login` – `developer21`, `password` – `123456` в которую кнопка "Войти" становится доступной, в противном случае `disabled`. Как это организовать с помощью `react`?

Comment: Как это организовать с помощью react? => При помощи языка javaScript и рук. Ну может быть немного ума и меньше Лени.

Comment: А если серьёзно, слушаем елемент событием например input. Проверяем, если.. value === strong, используя функцию создания состояния, пересоздаем с  try  на  false  или наоборот. В случае активности у вас перерисуется компонент, а дальше логика уже конкретно стилей. Например добавляем цвет.

Comment: @WalkMess что такое функция создания состояния?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ehmsx3?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: @Алексей спасибо помогло. Просто я абсолютнейший ноль в реакте.